# How to get VBA code with SAS Addin to work (InsertDataFromSASFolder)

Tags: excel, vba, sas

I am trying to get VBA to access a SAS dataset for use in an excel spreadsheet, there appears to be a specific Method for doing this but I can't get it to work as it keeps giving me an error.

My code as it stands looks like

```
Sub GetData()
Dim sas as SASExcelAddIn
set sas=Application.COMAddIns.Item("SAS.ExcelAddIn").Object
Dim data as SASDataView
set data =sas.InsertDataFromSASFolder ("path", Sheet1.Range("A25"),25,True,"","",True)
End Sub
```

The value of Path is a unix path to the folder with the dataset in, I have tried specifying this both with the dataset and without  and with the dataset without the file extension but I always get the error:
[image]

The only documentation I can find is https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/amodg/8.3/p11y2jzgivsqw4n1ixw5jjf22obd.htm but it is not solving my issue.

My aim will be to automate this to allow the folder to be changed and the SAS datasets referenced to update to the new data with just a single input. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of, and I don't use VBA with SAS, is this statement: "The data source must be saved in the metadata" at the top. Let me propose an alternative if someone doesn't solve it. Consider using VSTO (C#), vs VBA, and read the SAS dataset using ODBC or OLEDB. Much, much simpler and easier to debug scenario. VSTO allows you to create anything in the ribbon and relies on interop to work with Excel.

Good luck on getting an answer. Consider an alternative if you hit the wall.